# Getting errors after coding according to given suggestions

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have written the following code

```
class pass_check(ABC):
from Tkinter import *
def __init__(self):
   #------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.check=Tk()
    self.user=''
    ABC.__init__(self)
    self.pass_key=StringVar()
    self.E=Entry(self.check, bd=2, textvariable=self.pass_key)
    self.E.place(x=0, y=0)
    self.B=Button(self.check, text="Accept", command=self.check_pass(self.pass_key))
    self.B.place(x=50, y=50)
    self.check.mainloop()
def check_pass(fx):
    n=fx.get()
    if n=="25":
        print "Thank u"
    else:
        print "Incorrect"       


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass_check()
```

But I am getting the following errors can't understand how to get rid of them,

```
SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level
```

And

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1322, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1313, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Can anyone help me out

Comment: @BryanOakley It is different since I am working with an Entry Box, and the button is not taking the input from the input box, rather it keeps of prints "Incorrect"

Comment: The root of the problem is exactly the same.